# How can I parse emails client-side in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, mime-types, mime

I am using the GMAIL API similar to this question: [How do you get all the email body parts? And how do you know how many parts exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247686/how-do-you-get-all-the-email-body-parts-and-how-do-you-know-how-many-parts-exis)

I am having trouble parsing through the mime parts and creating the end message for the user.  What route can I take to decode these emails?  I would like to use something like [MailParser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser), but I need to do it on the client side.  What approach can I take using Javascript/jQuery?